# What is the purpose of Charts now that uiapp is deprecated?

Tags: google-apps-script

Now that uiapp is deprecated, it seems that there aren't really many ways to use Charts. HTML service doesn't support Charts, rather you have to use the other google Charts API.

[Source](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/)

I have a few questions:

1. Is there any use for Charts without uiapp?
2. Is it still possible to create a Charts dashboard using Charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check these [issue tracker 1](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1572) and [issue tracker 2](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2949) for references:

> Note that for static charts you can use **`Chart.getBlob().getImageUrl()`** to acquire an image to present.  You can also use Google Charts to create and manipulate charts with JavaScript and [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Also in the blog - [Converting from UiApp + Chart Service to Html Service + Google Visualization API](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/):

> For users of Google Apps Script, there are two alternatives for visualizing data:
>
> 1 **Continue using Charts + UiApp**. While deprecated and not supported for auto-completion in the editor, UiApp still works. There has been no announcement that it will actually be shut down… yet.
>
> 2. Follow Google’s recommendation, and **use HtmlService instead**. A [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1572) to have Charts supported by the HtmlService has been declined. So this seemingly-simple recommendation entails the additional requirement that you use Google’s other [Charts offering](https://developers.google.com/chart/), also known as the Google Visualization API, or GViz.

You can use HtmlService but as Mogsdad said "this seemingly-simple recommendation entails the additional requirement that you use Google’s other Charts offering." There are steps and sample in the issue tracker and blog for code implementation purposes.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll go ahead using the other charts offerings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20094-google-charts-dashboard-with-google-sheets) you can find what you need!

Comment: This is really cool, however it doesn't really answer my question. This uses the google visualization API, not the Charts that are built into Google Scripts.